# How will Flash work if the container html file and an embed swf file are from different domains?

Tags: flash

Let me give the context first. A user opens a local html file which has a reference to a network url of an swf file to embed. 
Then let me ask 2 questions.
(1) If the embed swf requests a local image file , will Flash allow the request?
(2) If the embed swf requests an image file on a non local url other than one of the swf file, will Flash check a crossdomain.xml file on the url?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1**: Yes, I tried this and it worked. I have a local HTML file which embeds a swf via the network. It loads the image from the network.

**Question 2**: Crossdomain xml would only work if you run the flash file on a domain. I think it might work if your flash file is accessible via a domain, like www.yourdomain.com/folder/flashfile.swf. Then you can give domain acces to www.yourdomain.com in the crossdomain.xml on the external server where you get the images from.